# WordPress refusing FTP connection when using correct details

Tags: wordpress, ftp, plugin

I am trying to update some plugins on a WordPress site.
To do this directly through WordPress you need to provide:

- Hostname
- Username
- Password
- Connection yype

I am definitely using the correct details however they are being refused.

An error is displayed:

> ERROR: There was an error connecting to the server, Please verify the settings are correct.

There is [a thread on the WordPress forum](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/failed-to-connect-to-ftp-server-1) asking similar question but there is no answer.

I have tried using my regular hostname in addition to `localhost`, `localhost:21` and `localhost:22`.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to make this work correctly?

Comment: are you using passive ftp? if so, does your server accept passive ftp?

Comment: I believe it is using active mode.

Comment: @TripleAntigen Thank you so much for this post. I installed the 'SSH SFTP Updater Support' pkg and Voila! I have been searching for a solution to this upgrade with my Host for months now. This fix took seconds. Give it a try if you are having trouble. I only needed to select the SSH2 option and enter my credentials that I was beginning to think were invalid! Thanks again.

Comment: If you are using AWS, make sure you specify the private IP of the server, not the public IP, because you cannot reach the public IP from the server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it were a folder permission error you would connect but get an error about permissions.

First enable WP_DEBUG in `wp-config`

If you have root access, check your php error log, and syslog in `/var/log`

From a shell, try FTPing to localhost does it work? Can you read and write to your `plugins` folder? Now also try from a remote machine FTPing into the server and again checking your read/write permissions.

Try setting the FTP details in `wp-config`

```
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'ftpext' );
define( 'FTP_BASE', '/path/to/wordpress/' );
define( 'FTP_CONTENT_DIR', '/path/to/wordpress/wp-content/' );
define( 'FTP_PLUGIN_DIR ', '/path/to/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/' );
define( 'FTP_PUBKEY', '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' );
define( 'FTP_PRIKEY', '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa' );
define( 'FTP_USER', 'username' );
define( 'FTP_PASS', 'password' );
define( 'FTP_HOST', 'ftp.example.org' );
define( 'FTP_SSL', false );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants

Figure out why you can't connect first. Then move on to folder permissions which is much easier to debug.

If you still have trouble just use this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/ssh-sftp-updater-support/

> Keeping your WordPress install up-to-date and installing plugins in a
>   hassle-free manner is not so easy if your server uses SFTP. "SSH SFTP
>   Updater Support" for WordPress uses phpseclib to remedy this
>   deficiency.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, I found a number of solutions in various forums, none of which helped. My credentials were OK but they were being rejected; they worked in Filezilla.

Somewhere I found a reference to a small plugin called 'SSH SFTP Updater Support', which fixed my problem. After installing this the option for SFTP is added and you can choose SSH2 when being challenged for the FTP login details.

Choose SSH2 at the bottom; and I didn't have to fill in anything in the private key box. Plugin deletion worked normally after that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your file and folder permissions and set them to the correct ones. Have a look here. 
http://www.electronicworkplace.com/latest-updates/wordpress-correct-permissions-for-files-and-folders
If you have the correct permissions then it won't ask you for ftp details.

If that doesn't work perhaps you have an ownership problem.

The other way to update is to manually upload the plugins to the plugins directory and update it that way.

Comment: Thanks for the link.
My permissions were fine except for .htaccess file which I've now changed.

I've eventually uploaded the individual plugins manually. 

Looking into ownership issues now.

Comment: @slaterio any luck?

Comment: I haven't uncovered anything unusual in the settings/permissions yet.

Comment: If you have a VPS and WHM make sure you're using suphp instead of DOS. That will get rid of all your file permission issues.

Comment: @AbuNoohThis link Broken.Please fix this

Comment: @SubodhJoshi see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, this page help me resolve it.

The cause of my issue is a file ownership issue.

Just make sure the files are owned by the correct owner/group